# How to set up Qt-Creator for Android?

Tags: android, c++, qt-creator

I've downloaded "android-studio-ide-192.6308749-linux.tar.gz" and extracted it and "android-ndk-r21-linux-x86_64.zip".

Now I don't know how to configure Qt-Creator to build android applications.

I am using Qt5-14 on Linux Fedora x64.

So can anyone help me to set it correctly? I've tried setting the paths: Android SDK location:

`/home/itachi/Downloads/android-studio-ide-192.6308749-linux/android-studio/`

and Android NDK location:

`/home/itachi/Downloads/android-ndk-r21-linux-x86_64/android-ndk-r21`

It seems to me that NDK is OK because all the checks are green but SDK `SDK tools installed` are red and `platform tools installed` also in red and `build tools installed` also in red and `platform SDK installed` in red too.

Comment: The SDK download is basically a few basic tools and a package manager. See the [Update your tools with the SDK Manager](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update) section of the Android documentation. Or do it from the command line with `$ANDROID_SDK/tools/bin/sdkmanager`

Comment: I@Botje: I've updated it to the latest version but still don't know how?

Comment: Did you install the packages in the [Recommended packages section](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update#recommended)?